# How to use CIRCOS plot pairwise syteny blocks for multi species

Tags: circos

Hi, I want to use Circos to draw syntenic relationships among multiple species, like the Fig.1b in this article. How to define the ideograms for different species?

Thank you.

https://doi.org/10.1038/s41588-024-01683-

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.